# change a value in db without redirect in symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, symfony-2.7

hi everyone I am working at symfony2.7 and my problem is when i want to check in  the checkbox, i want that the value change without redirect (cause in controller function i have to put a redirect) 
so i try something but it didn't work :s )
i wish that you help me
my problem is when i check the checkbox, nothing change in the db

this is my index.html.twig

```
<td>
{% if entity.etat==true  %}

<div   class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-{{ entity.id }}" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat"  checked="true" type="checkbox">
    <label  class="after" for="cmn-toggle-{{ entity.id }}"></label>
</div>
{% else %}<div   class="switch">
    <input id="cmn-toggle-{{ entity.id }}" class="cmn-toggle cmn-toggle-round-flat" type="checkbox">
    <label  class="after" for="cmn-toggle-{{ entity.id }}"></label>
</div>{% endif %}
```

```
<script>
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(e) {
var value = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Routing.generate('statut_root,{'id': entity.id}'),
    async: true,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function (msg) {
        if(data.result == 0) {
                for (var key in data.data) {
                    $(form.find('[name*="'+key+'"]')[0]).before('<ul class="errors"><li>'+data.data[key]+'</li></ul>');
                }
            } else {
            // Submit OK
            }
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

and this is my controller

```
public function StatutAction($id)
{ 
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $pros = $em->getRepository('SwibBundle:prospect')->find($id);
        if($pros->getEtat()==true){
        $pros->setEtat(false);
        }else if($pros->getEtat()==false){
        $pros->setEtat(true);
        }         
        $em->persist($pros);
        $em->flush();

    if ( $request->isXmlHttpRequest() ) {

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
            return array(
        'result' => 0,
        'message' => 'Invalid form',
        'data' => $this->getErrorMessages($form)
    );

       return array(
        'result' => 1,
        'message' => 'ok',
        'data' => ''
     );}

}

}
protected function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) 
{
    $errors = array();

    foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
        $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
    }

    foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
        if (!$child->isValid()) {
            $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
        }
    }

    return $errors;
}
```

and this is my router

```
statut_root:
path:    /statut/{id}
defaults: { _controller: SwibBundle:prospect:Statut}
```

Comment: And what's your problem? Any error? What happens? Is the request performed to the server?

Comment: If you want to work with your PHP array data in your Javascript, you may use the JsonResponse. Every controller actions has to return a Response object. `return new JsonResponse(array('result' => 1, 'message' => 'ok', 'data' => ''))`
Moreover, there is a typo in your code : the `msg` parameter of the ajax `success` method should be named `data`.

Comment: thank you guys for quickly answers, my problem is when i check the checkbox, nothing gona change in the db and i don't know why.
[see the exemple](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/711548etat.png)